# Firebase Phone Authentication broken after pod update

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, cocoapods

In my `setPhoneNumberVerificationID()` function, I am hitting this error:

> 'Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17053 "Remote notification and background fetching need to be set up for the app. If app delegate swizzling is disabled, the APNs device token received by UIApplicationDelegate needs to be forwarded to FIRAuth's APNSToken property." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Remote notification and background fetching need to be set up for the app. If app delegate swizzling is disabled, the APNs device token received by UIApplicationDelegate needs to be forwarded to FIRAuth's APNSToken property., error_name=ERROR_MISSING_APP_TOKEN}'

My `didReceiveRemoteNotification` function looks like:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(userInfo) {
            completionHandler(.noData)
            return
        }
    guard let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: AnyObject] else {
        completionHandler(.failed)
        return
      }
    print("got something, aka the \(aps)")
}
```

This is the setPhoneNumberVerificationID function:

```
func setPhoneNumberVerificationID(phoneNumber: String) {
        PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) { (verificationID, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error) //hitting this error here
            return
        }
        guard verificationID != nil else { return }
        print("error is: \(error) and verificationID is \(verificationID)")
        //do stuff with verificationID 
    }
}
```

As you can see below, my remote notification and background fetching is on.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPjxq.png

I had to very slightly change the .verifyPhoneNumber() arguments, because it used to take a 'uiDelegate: nil' parameter as well...how do I fix this???

Comment: What's not clear?  It says "ERROR_MISSING_APP_TOKEN."

Comment: Well I'm not sure how to fix it--this error wasn't occurring until I updated my pods. Also, something that's weird is a reCAPTCHA window that would pop up before now doesn't pop up, which is confusing me... @ElTomato

Comment: I guess I must have delete something by accident but I've gone through the documentation a million times and reimplemented phone auth and everything but can't find anything about an app token :/ I'm also not using FirebaseMessaging so it can't be anything to do with swizzling

Comment: A couple of things. Did you set the FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled flag to NO? Also, double check `setPhoneNumberVerificationID` as I believe there are two parameters.

Comment: Turns out I had to delete the pods from the pod file and reinstall them--for some reason when I updated them, it removed the GoogleTransportData pod and some others that were necessary for the implementation to work correctly. Thanks @Jay